# Is it possible to send SMS from phonegap HTML/Javascript application using Phone SMS API?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been trying to play with Phonegap and created a small application in HTML/Javascript to send an SMS. I tried this code `window.location.href = 'sms:XXXXXXXX06?body=Testing'` which opens up a screen to manually send the sms which I want to automate.

Please note that I create an android app by uploading my project source code to [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com), so I can not modify the `.apk` source.

Is it possible to do it in Javascript only?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Phonegap SMS plugin?

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? Would you like to share some links? Thanks!

Comment: I worked on an sms plugin that works with phonegap 3.x, but I don't know if it works with phonegap build: https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Phonegap SMS Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin) to send SMS messages.

Comment: Hey @dda, thanks for sharing it but I was already aware of such plugin. I've changed my approach to the problem and posted a new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11921401/415057), would like to hear your views?

Comment: hi i use the same code but i am getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sms' of undefined . I included the js file and putt the java file and permission too the error is at this window.plugins.sms.send($('#number').val(), 
    $('#message').val(), 
    function () { 
       alert('Message sent successfully');  
    },
    function (e) {
        alert('Message Failed:' + e);
    }
);

Answer (score 3):

here is the [phonegap-sms-plugin](https://github.com/javatechig/phonegap-sms-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

try to make somthing like this:

```
<a href="smsto:000000000"> sms number</a>
```

it works for me on Android device.