# How to send an SMS in Phonegap using Cordova Documentation?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

This is a followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916704/is-it-possible-to-send-sms-from-phonegap-html-javascript-application-using-phone) and I figured that we can access native functionality of the phone in javascript using [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/index.html) Documentation. I tried playing with notification api and it worked pretty well but could not find anything in the documentation about sending SMSes. I've come across [Phonegap-Start](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/) kit and [SMSPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin) for Phonegap but do not know how to integrate that with Phonegap-Start. In addition to it, I use [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) to build my application so I'm not using eclipse for the same which is why the readme file of SMSPlugin was not much for the help.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment.

It doesn't look like you can add your own plugins in Phonegap Build yet:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins

Moreover, SMSPlugin has not been officialy updated to work with Phonegap 2.0 yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PhoneGap plugins to do this, using html or js to open an "sms://" protocol link.  There is loose documentation all over the web on this (but not much officially from either Apple or Google developer sites).  There is a decent thread here on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link), including how the syntax changed for iOS 7+.