# Can PhoneGap read/write Android and iPhone's messages?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Can currently PhoneGap access both platforms's SMS messages?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916704/is-it-possible-to-send-sms-from-phonegap-html-javascript-application-using-phone

Comment: This is not even possible for native iOS. On native iOS you are only allowed to share by iMessage or SMS which opens a system dialog. So this would probably only work for Android.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't want to send, just read/write.

Comment: Downvoters should explain their downvote.

Comment: Ever heard of Sandbox...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow access to its SMS database even from native code, so it is not possible through PhoneGap either.

For Android it is not supported directly, but there is [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMS%20inbox_sent%20access) plugin. I am not sure how well it works though.