# Android - Phonegap, send SMS, Email, Share Facebook, Twitter

Tags: android, cordova, share

I have started developing a Phonegap app for android. I have some doubts implementing some features.

I have a text box and four buttons. The buttons are:

- SMS Button
- Email Button
- Twitter Button
- Facebook Button

When I click the sms button I want to open android native sms app. 
When I click the email button I want to open android native email app. 
When I click the twitter button I want to share the text present in the textbox.
When I click the facebook button I want to share the text present in the textbox.

Can any one help me on this? I know in native apps it's very easy, But I don't know how to do this on Phonegap apps.

Comment: have you,worked on these.did it work smoothly?

Comment: when i copied the javA file for e-mail from the link given below,it was showing errors.could not fix them. **I AM USING CORDOVA 2.1.0**

Comment: you need to change the package name in java file. also in the config.xml file you need to add this activity.

Comment: yeah did them,I got the problem with the **callbackcontext** in the line  `public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {` **and** this `import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;` **and** `CordovaPlugin` **and** the last method `The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) of type EmailComposer must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: did you add coredova.jar file into build path?

Comment: Amarnath,yeah cordova-2.1.0.jar

Comment: follow the steps in eclipse:   select the project -> click Project in menu -> click properties -> click Java compiler -> in the right side click the check box, enable project specific settings -> set the compiler compilation level to 1.6.    i think your problem will solve.

Comment: Amarnath, how did you implement it for the native apps.I have started with SMS and i found that it is retrieving the value from the HTML format.

Comment: for native apps, we don't need this plugins. we can achieve from share intent. this is for phonegap only.refer this for native http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

Comment: Amarnath,this SMS plugin too is not working,
THE message is not going.Even I want it for **PHONE GAP**

Comment: Amarnath, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666589/how-to-connect-an-application-with-the-social-networks-in-phone-gap)

Comment: i think it would be best to migrate to coredova 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use plugins for PhoneGap to do these things.

- [Plugin for SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916704/is-it-possible-to-send-sms-from-phonegap-html-javascript-application-using-phone)
- [Plugin for Facebook](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
- [Plugin for Email](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer)
- [Plugin for Twitter](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.cdvplugintwitter)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL@email.com>Email me</a>
```

In your html code will invoke the native email in android

```
 <a href="sms:212-111-4444>SMS me</a>
```

Will also do the native bit

```
fb://messaging
```

does stuff and

```
twitter://messages
```

Check out http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allows you to use the native sharing window of all mobile device. Give a try

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin