# How to connect a PHONE GAP application with FACEBOOK,TWITTER,SMS,EMAIL,LINKED-IN?

Tags: android, cordova, share, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phone gap-android.

I would like to access the social media network by the **respective native applications**.

- SMS
- FACEBOOK
- TWITTER
- EMAIL
- LINKED-IN

I am implementing it on a lower version of cordova. **CORDOVA 2.1.0**

Please suggest me Plug-ins preferably using JAVA SCRIPT.

uptill now,I have tried with SMS from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin).

It is not going to the native application.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this plugin for Facebook.I have developed an application using this plugin for Facebook.

[Facebook-plugin-For-Android](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect)

And From Here,You can browse for any plugins for any platform.

[Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)